# How to make TypeScript narrow the type of the parent object?

Tags: typescript

When I check the type of a property of an object, I expect the compiler to narrow the type of the property and the type of the object itself, but it only narrows the type of the property. Is there any way to change this behavior?

```
type A = { a: number };
type B = { b: number };
type X = { type: "a", value: A } | { type: "b", value: B };
type Y = { x: X };

function acceptsYWithTypeA(y: { x: { type: "a", value: A } }) {}

declare let y: Y;
if (y.x.type === "a") {
    const _0: { type: "a", value: A } = y.x; // No error because TS is narrowing `y.x`'s type.
    const _1: { x: { type: "a", value: A } } = y; // Error because TS is not narrowing `y`'s type.
    acceptsYWithTypeA(Object.assign({}, y)); // Same thing.
}
```

Comment: For how the linked question's answers apply to your code: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeUCGAuKA7ArgWwCMIAnKAXwG4AoUSKAIQWSgM10JPOtugA0mUPTACJUwgDRQAbqgA2OCJjhkoAH2ZCowghOlyFmRpRrhoATQFQAHpn7GqAMxxYAxsACWAeyxoXLiGDAAM5mAOruwAAWACqmMAAUIJgoNhqmImKSMvKKsOTkAJTIZFRUAPRlUABUNVCxdADmOKjEACZQTq4e3o7Obl4+kahB9RAJSVBmBZggUO5ByKlImqK62QawZCpIVFB7UMQQwDjEPiAAdFbnPAjwiKvUJVStEC6yLdCyR1ATZtTuDig8SGIziiQKRRQFWqtQAqkF3FgGnNgLt9i5vEFgFAAPoABmSUBWmT0OSU+UQFysFH2tKg0IAcp4oCRiJ5iGi9hisFjcQBGQlLInpLQk9a5ZQUn40vaM5ms9mc3z+QIhcJRUYJADyBAAVq9gOdhgiGlh4kgyJIQBCZXT6ZUmSziGyOWQgA

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks. Isn't there any other way? I'd rather not use a function.

Comment: I don't think so, no. Sometimes you need a function to manipulate types in TypeScript (odd though that seems). Don't worry about overhead, for two reasons: 1. Function calls are ***really*** cheap, and 2. If it's in a really performance critical part of your code, the JavaScript engine will inline the function call to get *that tiny bit more* speed.